# Laravel Join other tables in relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relationship, laravel-6

I have a Situation Like This:

User Model:

```
public function role() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\model\Roles' , 'id' ,'role');
    }

    public function userMetaData() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\model\UserMetaData' , 'user_id' ,'id');
    }

    public function userBet() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\model\UserBet' , 'user_id' , 'id');
    }

    public function userComission() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\model\UserComission' , 'user_id' , 'id');
    }

    public function userPartnership() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\model\UserPartneShip' , 'user_id' , 'id');
    }
    // Self Call
    public function parentData() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','parent_id');
    }
```

Controller

```
$userData = User::with(['userMetaData','userBet','userComission','userPartnership','role','parentData'])
                            ->where('id',$id)
                            ->get();
```

Now The Point Is In `role` i am getting the roles Of the User and In the `parentData` i am getting the creator of the user(parent) from the same user table by self calling now that parent also has a `role`

My Question Is How can i get that `role` object inside the `parentData`  Object?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all.. the relationship you've set is wrong it should be **belongsTo**

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\model\Roles' ,'role', 'id');
}

public function parentData() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','parent_id','id');
}
```

Now as you want `role` object inside the `parentData` set with as below.

```
$userData = User::with(['userMetaData','userBet','userComission','userPartnership','parentData.role'])
                  ->where('id',$id)
                  ->get();
```

Comment: Here i think the first `hasOne` `role` is for the user which data i want to pull

Comment: But i want to get the `role` related to the parent of that user also

Comment: You've set Hasone wrongly it supposed to be belongsTo..check for inverse relationship here.. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one.. If you do in with `'parentData.role'` you will get parent user with his role.

Comment: Try my answer and check and then let me know if the answer is not working perfectly.